# Do I have thousands of attempts to breach my system in this log from logwatch?

Tags: security, logs, fail2ban

I'm setting my systems up to send me reports by email. I'm posting one log report (see below). This log shows that there are thousands of attempted break-ins.

Questions:

1. I have `denyhosts` and `fail2ban` installed, why don't they block the
   IP's?
2. Is there a way to ban/black list IP's that show up in the logs like here?
3. What steps can I take against attacks like this?

   **NOTE:** `sshd` in the log, and note that there are IP addresses with
   thousands of log in attempts.
4. Why does it say: "ignoring max retries", can I set this up so it doesn't ignore "max retries"?

**NOTE:** My system is Fedora 20

---

#### Sample log

```
################### Logwatch 7.4.0 (03/01/11) ####################
        Processing Initiated: Tue Sep 16 03:35:07 2014
        Date Range Processed: yesterday
                              ( 2014-Sep-15 )
                              Period is day.
        Detail Level of Output: 0
        Type of Output/Format: mail / text
        Logfiles for Host: Hostname
 ##################################################################

 --------------------- Kernel Begin ------------------------

 WARNING:  Segmentation Faults in these executables
    polkitd :  2 Time(s)

 WARNING:  General Protection Faults in these executables
    traps: polkitd :  6 Time(s)

 WARNING:  Kernel Errors Present
    INFO: recovery required on readonly filesyste ...:  1 Time(s)
    ata2.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x100) ...:  14 Time(s)
    ata2.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x4) ...:  8 Time(s)
    ata2.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error ...:  10 Time(s)
    ata2: SError: { CommWake DevE ...:  52 Time(s)
    ata2: SError: { LinkSeq } ...:  8 Time(s)
    ata2: SError: { UnrecovData L ...:  2 Time(s)
    res 50/00:03:00:08:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error) ...:  5 Time(s)

 ---------------------- Kernel End -------------------------


 --------------------- pam_unix Begin ------------------------

 sshd:
    Authentication Failures:
       root (219.138.135.64): 3850 Time(s)
       root (122.225.103.125): 1016 Time(s)
       root (122.225.109.106): 256 Time(s)
       root (122.225.109.205): 194 Time(s)
       root (122.225.109.208): 183 Time(s)
       root (122.225.109.216): 178 Time(s)
       unknown (122.225.109.208): 63 Time(s)
       unknown (122.225.109.106): 57 Time(s)
       unknown (122.225.109.216): 54 Time(s)
       unknown (122.225.109.205): 22 Time(s)
       unknown (113.106.88.235): 14 Time(s)
       bin (113.106.88.235): 1 Time(s)
       nagios (113.106.88.235): 1 Time(s)
       tomcat (113.106.88.235): 1 Time(s)
    Invalid Users:
       Unknown Account: 210 Time(s)
    Unknown Entries:
       service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3: 945 Time(s)
       service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 5 > 3: 29 Time(s)
       service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 4 > 3: 6 Time(s)

 su:
    Authentication Failures:
       UserName(1000) -> root: 1 Time(s)
    Sessions Opened:
       UserName -> root: 6 Time(s)

 systemd-user:
    Unknown Entries:
       session opened for user UserName by (uid=0): 1 Time(s)


 ---------------------- pam_unix End -------------------------


 --------------------- Connections (secure-log) Begin ------------------------


 **Unmatched Entries**
    polkitd: <no filename>:0: uncaught exception: Terminating runaway script: 1 Time(s)
    polkitd: Acquired the name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 on the system bus: 3 Time(s)
    polkitd: Error evaluating authorization rules: 1 Time(s)
    polkitd: Finished loading, compiling and executing 6 rules: 3 Time(s)
    polkitd: Loading rules from directory /etc/polkit-1/rules.d: 3 Time(s)
    polkitd: Loading rules from directory /usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d: 3 Time(s)
    polkitd: Operator of unix-session:1 successfully authenticated as unix-user:root to gain TEMPORARY authorization for action org.freedesktop.problems.getall for system-bus-name::1.66 [/usr/bin/abrt-applet] (owned by unix-user:UserName): 2 Time(s)
    polkitd: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:1 (system bus name :1.70 [/usr/libexec/kde4/polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1], object path /org/kde/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_GB.UTF-8): 2 Time(s)
    polkitd: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:13 (system bus name :1.92 [/usr/libexec/kde4/polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1], object path /org/kde/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_GB.UTF-8): 2 Time(s)
    polkitd: Terminating runaway script: 1 Time(s)

 ---------------------- Connections (secure-log) End -------------------------


 --------------------- SSHD Begin ------------------------


 Disconnecting after too many authentication failures for user:
    admin : 30 Time(s)
    root : 937 Time(s)

 Failed logins from:
    113.106.88.235: 2 times
    122.225.103.125: 1016 times
    122.225.109.106: 256 times
    122.225.109.205: 194 times
    122.225.109.208: 183 times
    122.225.109.216: 178 times
    219.138.135.64: 3850 times

 Illegal users from:
    undef: 14 times
    113.106.88.235: 15 times
    122.225.109.106: 57 times
    122.225.109.205: 22 times
    122.225.109.208: 63 times
    122.225.109.216: 54 times

 Login attempted when shell does not exist:
    tomcat : 1 Time(s)


 Received disconnect:
    11: Bye Bye [preauth] : 16 Time(s)

 **Unmatched Entries**
 PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3 : 945 time(s)
 ecryptfs: pam_sm_authenticate: pam_ecryptfs: Error getting passwd info for user; rc = [0] : 210 time(s)
 PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 4 > 3 : 6 time(s)
 pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "nagios" : 1 time(s)
 PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 5 > 3 : 29 time(s)
 pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "bin" : 1 time(s)
 pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "root" : 5677 time(s)
 fatal: Write failed: Connection reset by peer [preauth] : 17 time(s)
 pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "tomcat" : 1 time(s)

 ---------------------- SSHD End -------------------------


 --------------------- Sudo (secure-log) Begin ------------------------


 UserName => root
 ----------------
 /bin/yum                       -   2 Time(s).

 ---------------------- Sudo (secure-log) End -------------------------


 --------------------- yum Begin ------------------------


 Packages Installed:
    binutils-2.23.88.0.1-13.fc20.x86_64
    libgomp-4.8.3-1.fc20.x86_64
    perl-Sys-CPU-0.54-5.fc20.x86_64
    VirtualBox-4.3.16-1.fc20.x86_64
    1:make-3.82-19.fc20.x86_64
    glibc-devel-2.18-14.fc20.x86_64
    logwatch-7.4.0-33.20140704svn198.fc20.noarch
    kernel-headers-3.16.2-200.fc20.x86_64
    glibc-headers-2.18-14.fc20.x86_64
    epylog-1.0.7-6.fc20.noarch
    perl-Sys-MemInfo-0.91-8.fc20.x86_64
    akmod-VirtualBox-4.3.16-1.fc20.x86_64
    gcc-4.8.3-1.fc20.x86_64
    dkms-2.2.0.3-25.fc20.noarch
    libgomp-4.8.3-1.fc20.i686
    patch-2.7.1-7.fc20.x86_64

 Packages Erased:
    kmod-VirtualBox-3.15.10-200.fc20.x86_64-4.3.14-1.fc20.6.x86_64
    kmod-VirtualBox-3.16.2-200.fc20.x86_64-4.3.16-1.fc20.x86_64
    kmod-VirtualBox-3.15.10-201.fc20.x86_64-4.3.14-1.fc20.7.x86_64

 ---------------------- yum End -------------------------


 --------------------- Disk Space Begin ------------------------

 Filesystem                                             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
 /dev/mapper/luks-                                      59G   55G  1.3G  98% /
 devtmpfs                                               5.8G     0  5.8G   0% /dev
 /dev/sda2                                              477M  131M  317M  30% /boot
 /dev/sda1                                              200M  9.5M  191M   5% /boot/efi
 /dev/mapper/fedora_Hostname-home                        395G  236G  156G  61% /home

 /dev/mapper/luks- => 98% Used. Warning. Disk Filling up.

 ---------------------- Disk Space End -------------------------


 --------------------- Fortune Begin ------------------------

 One man's brain plus one other will produce one half as many ideas as one
 man would have produced alone.  These two plus two more will produce half
 again as many ideas.  These four plus four more begin to represent a
 creative meeting, and the ratio changes to one quarter as many ...
                -- Anthony Chevins


 ---------------------- Fortune End -------------------------


 --------------------- lm_sensors output Begin ------------------------

 coretemp-isa-0000
 Adapter: ISA adapter
 Physical id 0:  +52.0 C  (high = +100.0 C, crit = +100.0 C)
 Core 0:         +52.0 C  (high = +100.0 C, crit = +100.0 C)
 Core 1:         +51.0 C  (high = +100.0 C, crit = +100.0 C)


 ---------------------- lm_sensors output End -------------------------


 ###################### Logwatch End #########################
```

#### EDIT #1

Apparently `fail2ban` was not running, I thought it was the same as `denyhosts`, which is set up automatically when installed.

Here's the output of `fail2ban-client`:

```
root ~ # fail2ban-client status
ERROR  Unable to contact server. Is it running?
root ~ # systemctl start fail2ban
root ~ # fail2ban-client status sshd
ERROR  NOK: ('sshd',)
Sorry but the jail 'sshd' does not exist
root ~ # fail2ban-client status
Status
|- Number of jail:      0
`- Jail list:
```

Comment: Are you shure `fail2ban` is running properly? `fail2ban-client status sshd` should tell you how many it's banned.

Comment: @garethTheRed You where right, it seems I need to configure fail2ban, see my edit.

Comment: I found this to configre fail2ban:http://apuntesderoot.wordpress.com/2014/02/27/configure-fail2ban-in-fedora-20-to-use-firewall-cmd-and-ipset/

Comment: You have to setup jails in `fail2ban` to have it filter and take an action when processing the log file defined for a given jail. You'll want to start by copying the `jail.conf` to a file called `jail.local`. You override and make customizations in the `jail.local` file, never the `jail.conf`.

Comment: Careful how you go.  I believe that the issues in that document have been fixed - https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1046816. Unfortunately, I'm not near my Fedora machine to check.

Comment: "can I set this up so it doesn't ignore 'max retries'" // Since it's setting them to a lower value, I doubt this is what you really want to do right now.

Comment: It's interesting that you have this issue around the same time as me on a RedHat7 system. I'm gonna try to search for some bug-reports on https://bugzilla.redhat.com to make sure it's not related to some recent update (unlikely) and/or a security flaw in some other packages; though, it may just be coincidence :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will attempt to specifically answer question 3 here as it appears you have found the configuration part of fail2ban which answers questions 1 and 2.  If want to beef up security on SSH I recommend the following.

1. Make sure that strict mode is set to true
2. Disable root logins
3. Change your SSH port
4. Disable password logins
5. Use port knocking

To answer your edit you will need to create an ssh config in /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/ssh.conf and paste the following...

```
[ssh]

enabled  = true
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 6
```

If you have already changed your port as I suggested you can set the port number here.  Restart fail2ban and test.

Comment: I don't understand the last part, what does "you can set the port number here" mean, did you intend to have a link in the "here" or something? I'm still a noob so please bear with me, your config file is different from what I found/followed, it was called jail.local. Does fail2ban have more than one confuration file?

Comment: Hi somethingSomething,If you have modified your SSH port as I suggested you can replace the "ssh" in your fail2ban ssh.conf - port = ssh with the port number that you changed the ssh port with (e.g. if you changed your SSH port to 1234 then you would need port = 1234).

Comment: I just checked something funny, I checked my password as I got a little worried about having all the attempts to breach security on my ssh port. It would take a desktop pc = "21 septillion years" to brake my password. Note this password was set before I saw that someone(probably multiple someone's) are trying to hack my ssh port.